# Possible cardinality of power sets

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals

What cardinals can provably not occur as the cardinality of a power set? I know that $\mathbb N$ and natural numbers that are not powers of two are such cardinals. What else is out there?

Comment: Infinite cardinals that are not powers of two can not occur.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Konig theorem says that 
$$\kappa < cf(2^{\kappa})$$ Thus if $cf(\lambda)=\omega$, such as $\aleph_{\omega}$ then $\lambda$ is not a power set.

Comment: And this is all that can be said - for any cardinal $\kappa$ of uncountable cofinality, there is a forcing extension preserving cofinalities such that $2^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Amazing! Took me some time to understand the terminology, that's why I haven't accepted until now. Noah: Do you have some source on this?

Comment: @M.Winter this is due to solovay, and see Easton's theorem for an extreme version.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I've always found such a description too imprecise. Surely if $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ no such extension exists for $\kappa=\aleph_1$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Argh, you're absolutely right - I always forget to include the "starting with a model of GCH" part. To M.Winter, note that every model $V$ of set theory has an inner model of GCH (namely its version of $L$), and every cardinal in $V$ is also a cardinal in $L$, so what *is* true is that if $\kappa$ is infinite with uncountable cofinality then there is always a forcing extension of *an inner model* of the universe in which $\kappa$ is a cardinal and $\kappa=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be an infinite set of cardinals and  let $x=\cup_{y\in S}2^y.$ Then $x$ is a strong limit cardinal: That is,  $\forall z<x\;(2^z<x).$  So $x$ cannot be a power cardinal.